# How to route WCF REST services?

Tags: wcf, rest, architecture, c#-4.0

Was planning to use Service Routing (on WCF/REST) to do some common tasks before a request hits the actual service. Now that I read more about it, looks like REST is not supported yet on RoutingService and the suggested method is to use System.Web.Routing or ARR.

What needs to happen in the router is a key validation, a header value extraction and versioning.

ARR doesn't look right for this as it just routes and there is no "handler" we have access to. System.Web.Routing looks like a lot of custom implementation which might undermine the efficiency of WCF.

An old school alternative am thinking of is to have the common functionalities in one chain-of-responsibilities implementation and just compose it in every service. This has the disadvantage of being referenced in N number of places for N services. But this increasingly looks like the only alternative if I don't want to mess with the WCF handling of endpoints.

Am looking for advice on a right way to do this, and any samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't try, but maybe writing a custom service behavior can solve your problem. Take a look here : [Extending WCF with Custom Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx).

The idea is to extend the WCF engine with a custom behavior, then attaching your service with this behaviors. This is transparent for the services.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Wrote service behavior extensions and associated these to the services where this validation need to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at HttpMessageHandlers in the new WCF Web Api project htttp://wcf.codeplex.com  This mechanisms allows you to do something similar to Rack or WSGI.  I have a couple of examples of what you can do with them on my blog http://www.bizcoder.com/index.php/2011/05/22/how-to-get-ahead-with-messagehandlers/